# Web 8.5 Topology Manager Installation Error

Tags: topology-manager, web8.5, installation

During the install of the Web 8.5 Topology Manager, the installer throws an error "A local error has occurred" and rolls back the Topology Manager install. Looking at the logs, we see the following error:

> Calling custom action
>   CommonCustomActions!CommonCustomActions.WindowsGroupCustomActions.CreateGroupExecute
>   Begin CreateGroupExecute CreateGroup: Unable to find the group
>   'WTSD5X1M\Topology Manager Users'. Creating new... CreateGroup: Unable
>   to find the group 'WTSD5X1M\Topology Manager Service Users'. Creating
>   new... CreateGroup: Unable to find the group 'WTSD5X1M\Topology
>   Manager Administrators'. Creating new... CreateGroupExecute: error A
>   local error has occurred.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean
>   throwIfFail)    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry
>   entry, String propertyName)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String
>   propertyName)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String
>   identityValue, DateTime refDate)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String
>   identityValue)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext
>   context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)    at
>   CommonCustomActions.WindowsGroupCustomActions.GetUserByName(PrincipalContext
>   context, String name)    at
>   CommonCustomActions.WindowsGroupCustomActions.CreateGroup(Session
>   session)    at
>   CommonCustomActions.WindowsGroupCustomActions.CreateGroupExecute(Session
>   session) MSI (s) (EC!E8) [13:17:49:143]: Product: SDL Web Topology
>   Manager -- A local error has occurred.
>
> A local error has occurred.
>
> CustomAction CreateGroupExecute returned actual error code 1603 (note
>   this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

We are running the installer as an administrator and installing on a fresh Windows Server 2012 server with SQL 2012.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved. Our architecture is multi-domain. We were trying to install from a shared support forest instead of the active run time environment. The bind was not able to execute to create the groups. After running the installer in the same run-time forest, the installer succeeded. Thanks!